# Laravel/PHP Shorthand for Namespaces Paths

Tags: php, laravel, class, namespaces

So, I've got a question that, while based in Laravel, might just end up being something basic in PHP that I either missed or forgot. Or it may just turn out there is no "textbook/clean/standard" way of doing it.

**A Question of Clutter**

Anyway, I'm creating a fair number of Form Requests in Laravel (it's a sizable "app") and I'm constantly struck by how unnecessarily redundant their inclusion can be:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;    

use App\Http\Requests\SubscriberRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SubscriberUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SubscriberExtRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SubscriberExtUpdateRequest;

class MailingListController extends BaseController
{


    public function store(SubscriberRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }


    public function update(SubscriberUpdateRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }


    public function ExtCreate(SubscriberExtRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }

    public function ExtUpdate(SubscriberExtUpdateRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }

}
```

**The Alternative**

Putting it up above moves the clutter out of the controller itself, but ends up being more work to create and maintain. I'm finding it's easier to just do it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;    


class MailingListController extends BaseController
{


    public function store(\App\Http\Requests\SubscriberRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }


    public function update(\App\Http\Requests\SubscriberUpdateRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }


    public function ExtCreate(\App\Http\Requests\SubscriberExtRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }


    public function ExtUpdate(\App\Http\Requests\SubscriberExtUpdateRequest)
    {
      // code here
    }

}
```

**The Question**

Obviously, either of these ways is "fine" and "valid." This is hardly a high-priority issue. But the form requests are all coming from the same namespace. And when I'm working with a couple dozen controllers, the typing/copying can get tedious.

So, with all that in mind, is there an "ideal" PHP class-based solution to this problem? And, failing that, should I resort to an app-wide constant/variable? (Or is there some other trick anyone would recommend?)

Comment: You could have `use \App\Http\Requests;` Then e.g. `ExtUpdate(Requests\SubscriberExtUpdateRequest)` as a middle ground

Comment: Using a decent IDE automates virtually all of the `use` statement creation. They’re still there, but that’s not any problem, and the IDE can mostly generate them automatically while you type. Having a number of such import/use statements at the top is typical in many languages.

Comment: @JonStirling I've actually seen that line near the top of controllers before, but for whatever reason, the developers that included it never actually did that "second step," so it never made sense to me. My thanks for the edification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using php 7+

Here is a nice way to keep your namespace inclusion cleaner.

```
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
```

Comment: That's actually a really awesome trick I had no clue about, and it works beautifully. And short of some Laravel-esque magic a la mutators and accessors, I dare say this is about as good as it's going to get. My thanks.

Comment: My pleasure.
Please let me know if you still stuck at any point.
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php for full reference on that topic